# Reading a particular value from a JSON tree using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to fetch one particular value from the JSON file provided below. Here is my code. I'm able to fetch all the Month data and store it to an array called `processed_json` and I'm facing an issue while fetching that particular value `D` from all the maps.

```
var processed_json=new Array();
var processed_json1=new Array();
$.getJSON("stack.json", function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.Sheet1["Month"].length; i++){
        processed_json.push(data.Sheet1["Month"][i]);
        processed_json1.push(processed_json["D"]);
    }
}
```

The value of D from all the maps must be stored into an array

[THIS IS THE JSON FILE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EoizTdpudCwT2UblW_ofJRY5Xio20MkD)

Comment: Could you post your json right here?

Comment: you have to parse the json before use using var data = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: @georg I have posted the Json file. Have a look

Comment: @georg as the json structure is big , i thought of posting the file itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Array.prototype.map for this:

```
 var result = data.Sheet1.Month.map(function(obj){
    return Object.values(obj)[0]['D'];
});
```

new filter requirement

```
var result = data.Sheet1.Month.filter(function (month) {
    return Object.keys(month)[0] !== 'BL';
}).map(function(obj){
    return Object.values(obj)[0]['D'];
});
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I need to ignore the first map which is BL and start from Jan till Dec. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You perform the loop through results correctly, and already save each entry in "Month" section of JSON into **processed_json** variable

So when you refer to data.Sheet1["Month"][i], you get a reference to an entry like this:

```
{"BL" : {
    "A" : 42,
    "B" : 19,
    "C" : 20,
    "D" : 11,
    "E" : 22,
    "F" : 44,
    "G" : 76,
    "H" : 12
  }
}
```

So the only step left is to make a reference to this object and then to a field D. You can do this either in object.field form or object["field"].

```
for (i = 0; i < data.Sheet1["Month"].length; i++){
  var entry = data.Sheet1["Month"][i];
  for(var key in entry){
    if(key == "BL"){
          break;
    }
    var D = entry[key].D;
    processed_json1.push(D);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or equivalently `processed_json1.push(data.Sheet1["Month"][i]["D"])` ;)

Comment: Can you offer some explanation with your code snippet?

Comment: I need the value of D from all the maps, I mean from January - December.

Comment: @alexzender but I need the value of D from all the maps. That is from Jan to Dec

Comment: Do you need it in array or you need to make some operation on it? In your example - the value of D will be gathered in processed_json1 array from all months. Please upvote and accept my answer if it helps you.

Comment: @alexzender I tried but its showing undefined, and i need the value of D from all the months i.e Jan- Dec .. According to my Json file the first map is BL I need to ignore that map and get the value of D from the next map(Jan-Dec)

Answer (score 0):

`processed_json` is an array, therefore it as no `D` property, you have to get the element *inside* `processed_json` to access `D`.

```
var processed_json=new Array();
var processed_json1=new Array();
$.getJSON("stack.json", function(data) {
for (i = 0; i < data.Sheet1["Month"].length; i++){
    var value = data.Sheet1["Month"][i];
    processed_json.push(value);
    processed_json1.push(value["D"]);
}
```